# Write output to new files at every nth iteration

Tags: c++, iteration

A fragment of my code is :

```
for (int iter = 0; iter < flags.total_iterations_; ++iter) {
  if (iter%20==0) {
      std::ofstream mf(flags.model_file_.c_str());
 accum_model.AppendAsString(word_index_map, mf); }
   else {
std::cout << "Model not created for "; }
  std::cout << "Iteration " << iter << " ...\n";
```

So, I am trying to generate outputs from method accum_model at every 20th iteration. But, the problem is I have to write the output in new file everytime the 20th iteration is reached. Now, my output is being overwritten.

I execute this code with the help of a executible, which is as:

```
 ./lda --num_topics 15 --alpha 0.1 --beta 0.01 --training_data_file testdata/test_data.txt --model_file MF/lda_model.txt --burn_in_iterations 120 --total_iterations 150
```

The MF/lda_model.txt is the output file given. I am not understanding how to link the file that contains the code and this executible command as I would need 5 different new files (for 100 iterations - as data is written into a new file every 20th iteration).

I am new to coding and so far, I was coding in python. I tried till this loop, I am confused about how to create new files and get corresponding outputs. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an issue with creating more files?

Comment: As in for this code, the output file is created in the name lda_model.txt and the outputs at every 20th iteration are overwritten in this file and am only getting the final 100th iteration's output in the file. But, I am  not understanding how to create new files at every 20th iteration and write the output.

Comment: You need to change the name of the file created, since standard mode for `ofstream` is creating a new file to write OR overwrite existing file. Also, in [C++11 `ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/) can take `std::string` as argument in constructor:

`std::ofstream mf(flags.model_file_ + std::to_string(iter));` //
[to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) — only in C++11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use std::stringstream, and build a new file name to open each time.

```
std::string uniquePathFileNamePostFix (int i) {
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << '-' << i ;    
   return (ss.str());
}
```

The idea is to use the stringstream to create (or append or prepend) a unique modifier based on i. (or anything else convenient - I have used time stamps).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are overwriting the ofstream instead of appending to it.

You'll want to specify the 'app' flag in the mode of the ofstream constructor:

```
std::ofstream mf(flags.model_file_.c_str(), std::ios_base::app);
```

If you need to start the output with an new, "empty" file, just leave out the mode (ofstream defaults to std::ios_base:out, whether you specify it or not): [std::ofstream::ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/)

...and if you need a new output file (according to your OP), you need to change the file name in flags.model_file_.

Comment: No, I want to create individual output files instead of appending and get the output. So if I have 100 iterations, I should be having 5 individual output files and I should get the corresponding outputs.

Comment: Hmmm.. there doesn't seem to be enough information to find a solution. flags.model_file_.c_str() doesn't change (in your OP), and unless there are side effects (from accum_model.AppendAsString), the output file will just keep getting overwritten (e.g. 5 times for 100%20) and you will be left with just the last iteration of the loop's output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly, but I think you want to output every 20th iteration in a new file. To do so, you just need to append the value of the`iter` to the name of the file or otherwise add a "dynamic" element to it.

The way to do it using only standard C++ is using stringstream:

```
    std::stringstream file_name;
    file_name << flags.model_file_ << iter;
    result = file_name.str();
```